# Can I make a FastAPI endpoint receive json OR a file

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to make a FastAPI endpoint where a user can upload documents in json format or in a gzip file format. I can get the endpoint to receive data from these two methods alone/separately, but not together in one endpoint/function. Is there a way to make the same FastAPI endpoint receive either json or a file?

Example with json:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Document(BaseModel):
    words: str


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/document/")
async def create_item(document_json: Document):
    return document_json
```

Example with file:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.middleware.gzip import GZipMiddleware


app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(GZipMiddleware)


@app.post("/document/")
async def create_item(document_gzip: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return document_gzip
```

Not working example with either-or:

```py
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.middleware.gzip import GZipMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Document(BaseModel):
    words: Optional[str] = None


app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(GZipMiddleware)


@app.post("/document/")
async def create_item(
    document_json: Document, document_gzip: Optional[UploadFile] = File(None)
):
    return document_json, document_gzip
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a FastAPI endpoint that can accept either Form or JSON body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74009210/how-to-create-a-fastapi-endpoint-that-can-accept-either-form-or-json-body)

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) as well.

Answer (score 2):

In your "not working example" with both options, made the json document mandatory. That is, the parameter has to be provided. I guess that posting the json document but not the file works, but the other way around fails. Am I right?

Anyways, the correct code should look as follows (note: I did not test it):

```
@app.post("/document/")
async def create_item(
    document_json: Document = None, document_gzip: Optional[UploadFile] = File(None)
):
    # Check that either are not none
    return document_json, document_gzip
```

#### EDIT based on your comment:

It could be due to how `Fastapi` processes the request for you. Since you specify both `JSON` and `File` from the body, it could be that `Fastapi` uses just the last (it's only my assumption, could be interesting exploring that). So it will always consider all parameters (except for `GET`) as file objects and check in the request's body for files.

You could try playing around with the raw `Request` object in order to check the body for any `JSON`.

Below a potential example what it could look like. Since `Fastapi` is based on `Starlette`, several features are shared between the two. The `Request` object is among those. Here are the docs with more info (in case you need it)

https://www.starlette.io/requests/

Below the updated example, which I did not test, but should work

```
@app.post("/document/")
    async def create_item(
        req: Request, document_gzip: Optional[UploadFile] = File(None)
    ):
        if document_gzip is None:
            # Maybe use a try except (i.e. try-catch) block... just in case
            document_json = await req.json()

        # Check that either are not none
        return document_json, document_gzip
```

Comment: Actually neither work in my "not working example" with the return body showing something like `{"detail":[{"loc":["body","documents_json"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}`. If I make your suggested change, both return status code 204 as if they both work, and the gzip file works, but the json does not actually accept json, I just get the `null` back (which is different from the working "example with json" where I actually receive the json data back.

Answer (score 1):

My working sample based on [previous response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65330840/1214729):

```py
async def invocations(input: Request, input_file: Optional[UploadFile] = File(None)):

    if input_file is None:
        input_json = await input.json()

    if input_file is not None:
        input_df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(input_file.file.read()))
        return models.get("model").batch_predict(input_df=input_df)
```

Request with json:

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/invocations' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "first_attr": 10,
    "second_attr": "all good"
}'
```

Request with file:

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/invocations' \
--form 'input_file=@"/absolute-path-to-file/some-json-file.csv"'
```

Downside is that generated docs are not reflecting this behavior (have not tried to fix this yet):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done.

> You can declare multiple File and Form parameters in a path operation,
> but you can't also declare Body fields that you expect to receive as
> JSON, as the request will have the body encoded using
> multipart/form-data instead of application/json.
>
> This is not a limitation of FastAPI, it's part of the HTTP protocol.

You can, however, use Form(None) as a workaround to attach an extra List or similar types as form-data

Here is the snippet I used for this use case

```
@extract_operations_router.post("/runcompletepipe")
async def runcompletepipeline(urls: Optional[List[HttpUrl]] = Form(None),files : Optional[List[UploadFile]] = File(None)):
    print(urls,files)
    # for file in files:
    #     print(file.filename)
    return('qapairslist')
```